# Merge several rows to own row by value of one column in MySQL

Tags: mysql

i have a table like this one:
There are some rows with the same value in col2 and e.g. for every 't1' is only one value in col3 (and so on), no duplicates.

[image]

and I want to have a query for this result:

[image]

with

`SELECT * FROM table GROUP BY col2`

i get no all values for t1 e.g..

Comment: Perhaps if the example was a little less abstract

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pick min/max value per group as

```
SELECT 
max(col1) col1, 
col2,
max(col3) col3,
max(col4) col4,
max(col5) col5,
max(col6) col6,
max(col7) col7
FROM table 
GROUP BY col2
```

Comment: Thank you for this very quick answer. I have some hundred cols. There is not any other solution for this problem, is it?

Comment: As far as i know, No you need to specify each col

Comment: Thank you. And is there a way to preserve the col1? with concat?

Comment: Sorry i didn't get you ? Preserve col1 ?

Comment: In col1 I have the values 1,2,3 i.e. and after the query I get only one value.

Comment: So you want all values for col1 per group?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155023/discussion-between-shenya-and-m-khalid-junaid).